# How to use Layer defined by Cocos2d Studio in Cocos2d-JS?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I have used Cocos2d Studio to create a layer (`layer_main.json`) and add some button to it.
Now, i want to load it in main scene and manipulate with buttons.

Can i put code in a separate file (like `src/mainLayer.js`) that defined by cc.Layer.extend({}). I try use `ccs.load`, `ccs.uiReader`. Can anyone help me?